# Ubuntu/KVM - Iptables NAT rules to forward ports from Host to Guest dont work right, (affects http)

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, kvm-virtualization, nat, timeout

To put this in context I installed **Ubuntu 17.04** and installed **KVM** then successfully configured a Windows Server 2016 standard virtual machine. Network/internet-access wise everything was working perfectly fine until this morning I noticed that when navigating in a browser I cannot access certain websites. I have found the source of the problem but my knowledge with **iptables** is minimal and after countless hours of research I still haven't figured out.

Here are the effects of the problem.

- HTTP**S** webites work.
- HTTP websites do not work (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)
- My IIS website on HTTP does work and is accessible from anwhere

I am using a NAT connection between my Host and Guest. I use **/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu** script provided by them to forward ports and I have found the source of the problem **(Numbered 1 and 2 below)**

Edit: I put those up here to see better:

> 1- sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to
>   $GUEST_IP:80
>
> 2- sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT
>   --to-destination $GUEST_IP:80

I have tried both of them individually and they work for a few moments then I cant access http websites anymore but my webserver is stil accessible.

I would appreciate any help or new/different rule that might solve this problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "${1}" = "VM-NAME" ]; then

   GUEST_IP=10.0.0.5
   # currently not used anywhere
   HOST_IP=1.2.3.4

   # CURRENTLY NOT USED, use as $HOST_PORT or $GUEST_PORT
   #GUEST_PORT=3389
   #HOST_PORT=1338

   if [ "${2}" = "stopped" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
        /sbin/iptables -D FORWARD -o virbr0 -d  $GUEST_IP -j ACCEPT
        ##/sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -m state 10.0.0.0/24 --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

        #### RDP [tcp/udp] [Host:1338 -> VM:3389]
        /sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1338 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:3389
        /sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p udp --dport 1338 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:3389

        #### HTTP [tcp] [Host:80 -> VM:80]
        1- ##/sbin/iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:80
        2 -##/sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination $GUEST_IP:80
   fi
   if [ "${2}" = "start" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
        /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -d  $GUEST_IP -j ACCEPT
        ##/sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -m state 10.0.0.0/24 --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

        #### RDP [tcp/udp] [Host:1338 -> VM:3389]
        /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1338 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:3389
        /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport 1338 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:3389

        #### HTTP [tcp] [Host:80 -> VM:80]
        1- ##/sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to $GUEST_IP:80
        2- ##/sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination $GUEST_IP:80

   fi
fi
```

My ifconfg is the following if you might need it. virbr0 is the bridge between the host and the vm I assume and vmnet0 only appears when the vm is running.(I dont quite understand why vnet0 is only ipv6 tough)

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet <my ipv4> netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast <my ipv4>.255
        inet6 <my ipv6>  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 <my ipv6> prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 4c:72:b9:43:f0:e5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 18640  bytes 2965981 (2.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16930  bytes 3893649 (3.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xfe500000-fe520000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 164  bytes 33947 (33.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 164  bytes 33947 (33.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        ether 52:54:00:62:88:21  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10302  bytes 2798316 (2.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9209  bytes 1691107 (1.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc7f:f3ff:fe5e:e777  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:7f:f3:5e:e7:77  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10302  bytes 2942544 (2.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13079  bytes 1893103 (1.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Still no answer so far...